# How is Airbnb.com using iOS universal links from the same domain?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

In Apple's [Universal link documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) it says it will respect a users assumed intent to open a web browser link instead of the iOS application if a universal link is clicked on from the same domain.

> When a user is browsing your website in Safari and they tap a universal link to a URL in the same domain as the current webpage, iOS respects the user’s most likely intent and opens the link in Safari. If the user taps a universal link to a URL in a different domain, iOS opens the link in your app.

But if you go to Airbnb.com on mobile Safari, select a room, then select the location on the room's page (e.g. "Seattle, Washington, United States" on [this](https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/16617445?adults=1&check_in=2021-02-24&check_out=2021-02-28&source_impression_id=p3_1606016614_w9hqsoWCHDFw0gDX&guests=1) room's page) the application will be opened despite being on the same airbnb.com domain.

Is this because the user is on "www.airbnb.com" and the link is just "airbnb.com" (omitting the 'www') and Apple is interpreting this as a separate domain?

Comment: The trick of not putting "www" works for me !

Answer (score 2):

The "Seattle, Washington, United States" link you mentioned has a `target="_blank"` attribute:

```html
<a rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" href="https://airbnb.com/s/Seattle,Washington,United%20States/homes?_ga=2.251994633.1860762053.1606031441-1112301665.1606031441" class="_5twioja">Seattle, Washington, United States</a>
```

This instructs Safari to open the link in a new tab. Thus, this link escapes the navigation rule, since opening a new Safari tab would behave the same as trying to open that link from non-Safari apps.

If the link wouldn't have that attribute, then it would've been opened in the same Safari instance. So the Apple rules still apply, just that opening a new tab leads to switching to the Airbnb application due to the implicit behaviour if the `target` attribute.

If you want to be explicit, you can long press the link, and choose "Open in New Tab", this will keep you in Safari too.

Comment: This seems to be no longer working, at least in my version of iOS (14.6). Tapping a link with `target="_blank"` opens a new Safari tab, instead of the Airbnb app.